# Navigation Architecture Component - Unable to navigate to fragment from onResume

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I'm testing this new library out and want to navigate to a login fragment if the user isn't signed in. This check is done in in a base fragment like:

```
abstract class SignedInFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser == null) {
        NavHostFragment.findNavController(this /* Fragment */)
                .navigate(R.id.action_login)
    }
}
```

}

But this just ends up in a RuntimeException saying FragmentManager is already executing transactions:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {me.hammarstrom.loco/me.hammarstrom.loco.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3645)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3685)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2898)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

The navigation graph looks as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
    android:name="me.hammarstrom.loco.ui.login.LoginFragment"
    android:label="LoginFragment" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_signedInFragment"
        app:destination="@id/signedInFragment"  />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/signedInFragment"
    android:name="me.hammarstrom.loco.ui.common.SignedInFragment"
    android:label="SignedInFragment" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    android:name="me.hammarstrom.loco.ui.main.MainFragment"
    android:label="MainFragment" />
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_login"
    app:destination="@id/loginFragment" />
```

Should this kind of navigation be done in some other way? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a bug in Android Architecture Components. I created a bug report regarding this issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79632233). I've found that temporary workaround for it is to delay the call to the navigation method so that the fragment manager can execute pending transactions.

```
val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
executor.schedule({
        activity?.runOnUiThread { NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
            .navigate(R.id.action_login) }
}, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

or if you are using coroutines

```
launch(UI) {
    delay(1L)
    NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.action_login)
}
```

**UPDATE:**

This issue has been fixed in version `1.0.0-alpha02`.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in `Navigation 1.0.0-alpha02`. Based on [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes):

> Fixed an IllegalStateException when calling navigate from Fragment
>   lifecycle methods